# Matlab: Remove field from nested struct

Tags: matlab, struct

Consider the nested struct:

```
>> clear x;
>> x.y.a = 1;
>> x.y.b = 2;
>> x.y

ans = a: 1
      b: 2
```

I can't see to remove the field `a`:

```
>> rmfield( x.y , 'a' );
>> x.y

ans = a: 1
      b: 2
```

Can anyone please provide insight into why the `rmfield` function doesn't seem to be working, and how I can actually remove a field from a nested struct?

I am using R2015b, but I get the same results with [R2018a](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-online.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for `rmfield` is

```
s = rmfield(s,field)
```

(see the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rmfield.html)).

So you need to write:

```
x.y = rmfield( x.y , 'a' );
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Cris!  Yes, I did read the documentation, but I find it so easy to overlook such a detail (wouldn't be the first time).  For this reason, I hope that thread is not too trivial to keep on Stack Exchange, to help the many others who may run into this.  I'm assuming, of course, that it's not just a personal blind spot.